# Spark tunables specially executor-memory

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

`time ../bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 3G --num-executors 100 /var/tmp/learning/Movie-Similarities-1m-hdfs.py  260`​​

took: 6m5.293s​

`time ../bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 2G --num-executors 100 /var/tmp/learning/Movie-Similarities-1m-hdfs.py  260`​

took: 5m46.234s​

`time ../bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 3g --executor-memory 4G --num-executors 100 /var/tmp/learning/Movie-Similarities-1m-hdfs.py  260​`

took: 9m35.313s​

I know that I have(purposely) oversubscribed on the num-executors, that was simply to get the most out of the cluster.

Any observations on these results?

Comment: how many times did you run each to get result?

Answer (score 0):

> Any observations on these results?

Your code is running faster with more executors (with less memory) than fewer executors (with more memory). There generally is an optimal balance that will be dependent on the workflow and the cluster's hardware. The only way to really find this optimal point is by trial and error.

That said, I've generally found fewer executors with more resources to typically perform better. One thing you haven't attempted to control is the number of CPU cores that the executors will use. In order to start an executor, there will need to be enough free memory AND enough CPU cores. If both of your tests are memory bound (eg the resource manager ran out of memory before it ran out of cores), then the 2G executor test would be utilizing twice as many CPU cores as the 4G test. If both tests are CPU core bound, then the 4G test will utilize twice the memory of the 2G test.

Long story short, it'd be worthwhile to consider the number of cores each executor gets. I've created a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VH7Qly308hoRPu5VoLIg0ceolrzen-nBktRFkXHRrY4/edit#gid=0) that should help you manage these tradeoffs.